# Reading of the article “an” preceding quotations

Tags: pronunciation, articles, quotations

Speakers often add “quote” or “quote, unquote” before quotations.  But when a quotation is preceded by the article “an”, how should that article be pronounced?

As I understand, the choice between “a” and “an” is determined by what phonetically follows the article.  When “quote” or “quote, unquote” is inserted between “an” and the quotation, the extra “-n” becomes unnecessary.  So should I really pronounce “a” instead?

Comment: We have [an amazing blog article](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) that might help you out.

Comment: Can you give some explicit examples of what the problem is, giving contrasting examples? As is, it is unclear what you are asking about, the pronunciation of 'an' or 'un-' or 'an un-' or what.

Comment: @MattЭллен So basically this is a case of “Parenthetical Statements” and my guess is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, I would say *quote, unquote* is a parenthetical statement. You are correct.

Comment: @Mitch  I was asking about pronunciation of the article “an” before a quotation when the quotation marks are read out as “quote” or “quote, unquote”.

Comment: OK. Then it would really help if you gave explicit examples, in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morphology of articles is entirely a matter of phonology (i.e, **sound**). It's very simple and completely general.

The indefinite article allomorph *a* is used before a consonant, and *an* is used before a vowel; similarly, the definite article allomorph /ðə/ is used before a consonant, while /ði/ is used before a vowel. **Whatever** sound follows the article determines the allomorphy; never mind whether it's what the article modifies. And since consonants and vowels are the only two kinds of speech sound, this exhausts all possibilities.

Parenthetical words therefore fall under the rules; **everything** falls under the rules. So, since *quote* /kwot/ starts with a consonant /k/, an indefinite article preceding it should be *a*.

> (The terms  *"vowel"* and *"consonant"*, by the way, refer only to **spoken** vowels and consonants, **not** written ones; that's why *an hour* and *a useful tool* are correct, while **a hour* and **an useful tool* are incorrect.)

Comment: So, just so I'm understanding, if the sentence is written down and punctuated so that *quote, unquote* is a parenthetical statement, say, like this: I would object to him being a (quote, unquote) expert witness. You should use *a* not *an*?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you should use _a,_ not _an._

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure I would have guessed this.

Comment: The trick is to remember that real language is spoken, while written language is technology. Therefore real language rules have to do with sound, not spelling.